# Spring - Use Both JPA Repository and JdbcTemplate Datasources

Tags: java, spring, jpa

How can I properly implement 2 datasources in a single class - 1 utilizing Spring's jdbcTemplate and the other using a Spring JPA Repository?

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("DataSource1")
public void setDataSource1(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

@Qualifier("DataSource2")
private final MyRepository repo;
```